# how to create "trigger after update of a table on multiple column" in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I'm going to create a trigger before/after update on specific columns of a table in postgresql but i can't do that.

i can bind trigger to fire after update a specific column of a specific table but i can't do that for more than one column. i want to know is it possible?

i don't want to solve it using writing IF(UPDATE(column series)) in my trigger function

--i tried below code but it give me error near ','

```
    create trigger save_information after update of table_name on day, month
    for each row
               execute procedure save_function();
```

-- but below code (by mentioning just a single column) works fine:

```
    create trigger save_information after update of table_name on day
    for each row
               execute procedure save_function();
```

i don't want to change my save_function to solve it or use 'IF(update(column series)' statement.
excuse me for my weak writing.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message please?

Comment: the exact error is:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "," 

LINE 28: ...formation after update of table_name on day , month... ^

 SQL state: 42601 

Character: 1061

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) the column name(s) are listed after the `OF` keyword.

So it should be:

```
create trigger save_information 
     after update of day, month
     on table_name 
for each row execute procedure save_function();
```

Comment: thank you very very much.
it solved the problem.
excuse me if it was so simple:|